# SOA SUITE 11g - Business Rules - Compare Dates/DateTime

Tags: datetime, oracle11g, jdeveloper, business-rules, soa-suite

Good morning.

I have a problem with using business rules to Compare Dates.

I want to compare an input date vs current date.

The input message ( in this case the date that i want to compare) is a structure fieldname/fieldvalue.

->Example of the input:

```
        <fiel:field>
           <fiel:fieldName>mydate</fiel:fieldName>
           <fiel:fieldValue>1998-01-13T10:34:39.018</fiel:fieldValue>
        </fiel:field>
```

I want to compare this fieldValue with the current Date, and define the output message based on the result.

My jdevelepor has the version 11.1.1.4.

I tried to define a function to do this, but i was not very sucessfull.

Any help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the XPAth date functions and String functions to do date and string manipulation to get your payload sin the format you want them.